# Can I use WorkManager to implement a use case in Android Java where I need to call API for every 15 minutes and update the UI when app is open?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-intentservice

Should I use WorkManager or is there any other better approach. Also, I want to use Retrofit to call the API every 15 minutes. WorkManager will execute the tasks even if we Kill the app but I only need to call API when the app is open. WorkManager is specifically for requests that need to persist and execute at some point.

When I cancel the work in onDestroy() it is not working as expected as onDestroy() will not be executed if we force close the app. How can I cancel the work in the work manager in order to meet my use-case of calling the API only when the app is open? Is the work manager intended for my use case?

Comment: Did you try to cancel work manager during onPause ?

Comment: If I try to cancel the workmanager during onPause() then if the other activity comes in on top my activity then it will cancel the work manager

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this https://androidwave.com/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android-workmanager/